Unable to connect to new redis install through PHP, but it's otherwise working
Setup a new RHEL server, installed redis and php-pecl-redis6. I can connect with redis-cli no problem, so the server is definitely running. But when I try to use $redis->connect('localhost', 6379);, it throws a RedisException of permission denied. That's definitely the correct port. What could be causing this issue?
EDIT: Closing due to the solution being found here:
Troubleshooting "Permission denied" when attempting to connect to Redis from PHP script

Have you checked this question/answer Troubleshooting "Permission denied" when attempting to connect to Redis from PHP script?

@M.Eriksson that solved it. I'll close this question.
